# Removing "Powered by eCommerce Software"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove the "Powered by Americommerce" text in the footer of my website, https://www.metaldepotinc.com/
Problem is, the html for this link is no where to be found in any of the footer's html. There is no file on the backend of my website that has the coding I found by inspecting the page in Chrome. Upon inspection, I found out the id of the element is "AmeriCommerce-powered-by-link"

Is there a code I could use to remove this element?

Comment: Do you have their permission to remove that? If not, this is extremely unethical and I do not support this kind of question.

Comment: Have you tried css? `body { display: none}`

Comment: I chatted with a support tech at AmeriCommerce who said: "If you create a support ticket then we'd be able to remove the link at the bottom of the page".

Comment: This worked: #AmeriCommerce-powered-by-link{
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Simply finding the correct class name/ID and setting it to display: none; should solve the issue for you, if you're unable to remove it from the html directly.

Using any modern browser, you can access the element inspector/development tool to find the class name. On the piece of text you're wanting to remove, right-click --> inspect(some browsers will have a different name for this, typically under development tools), and then note the class name/id of the element.

Then, in your Theme's main CSS file, add this

```
#elementID , .elementName {
display: none !important;
}
```

Using !important is typically bad practice, but in this case it may be necessary if they also have styling hidden somewhere to make it visible.

---

Now, the other side of this:

Are you sure that you are ***allowed*** to remove this line? Most ECommerce platforms put this tagline at the bottom of the page because, at the end of the day, you are using their platform. At least one platform I have used in the past has had the tagline be a requirement in the ToS, as it is the only form of advertisement they get from your site.

I would recommend contacting support for your platform and asking them, directly, if removing this is something you are allowed to do. If it is not, and you don't contact them first, you run the risk of them pulling your site down without warning.